# Restore corrupted TFS files from $tf\ .gz files?

Tags: azure-devops

My hard disk had errors and I lost a number of files before they could be checked in. But I'm wondering if there's a way to look in the \$tf folder's .gz files to restore the files that were lost and not checked in? Any chance a diff version was saved in there that I can restore from?

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm wondering if there's a way to look in the \$tf folder's .gz files to restore the files that were lost and not checked in?

I am afraid you could not to restore the files based on the `.gz` files.

The `.gz` files are generated when mapping sources, which keeps a hash and some additional information on all file in the workspace so that it can do change tracking for Local Workspaces and quickly detect the changes in the files. **But** it does not contain source files. If you do not check the source files in the source control, TFS could not restore those files from the source.

To restore those files, you need to find a way to recover hard disk data.

Hope this helps.